# $\int \frac{1}{48!} (t^{48}) (e^{-t}) \, dt$

Tags: integration

What is the integral from 0 to 30 of:

$\int \frac{1}{48!} t^{48} (e^{-t}) \, dt$

I tried integration by parts but it gets more complicated! Is there another simpler way?

Comment: I doubt this has a nice closed form expression.. In any case look up gamma and incomplete gamma function

Answer (score 4):

Integration by parts results in 
$$
\int \frac{t^{48}}{48!}e^{-t}dt
=-\frac{t^{48}}{48!}e^{-t}+\int \frac{t^{47}}{47!}e^{-t}dt
$$
You can continue with the remaining integral in the same way and each time the factorial and the exponent will decrease by one, such that you finally get
$$
\int \frac{t^{48}}{48!}e^{-t}dt
=
-\sum_{k=0}^{48}\frac{t^k}{k!}e^{-t}
=
-e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{48}\frac{t^k}{k!}
$$

Comment: It is probably also noteworthy to note that the sum is the initial part of the exponential series, which can be useful when inserting the integration limits.

Answer (score 0):

Something humorous: Maxima's output.

integrate(t^(48)*%e^(-t)/factorial(48),t);

gives us

((-12413915592536072670862289047373375038521486354677760000000000-12413915592536072670862289047373375038521486354677760000000000*t-
6206957796268036335431144523686687519260743177338880000000000*t^2-2068985932089345445143714841228895839753581059112960000000000*t^3-
517246483022336361285928710307223959938395264778240000000000*t^4-103449296604467272257185742061444791987679052955648000000000*t^5-
17241549434077878709530957010240798664613175492608000000000*t^6-2463078490582554101361565287177256952087596498944000000000*t^7-307884811322819262670195660897157119010949562368000000000*t^8-
34209423480313251407799517877461902112327729152000000000*t^9-3420942348031325140779951787746190211232772915200000000*t^10-310994758911938649161813798886017291930252083200000000*t^11-
25916229909328220763484483240501440994187673600000000*t^12-1993556146871401597191114095423187768783667200000000*t^13-142396867633671542656508149673084840627404800000000*t^14-
9493124508911436177100543311538989375160320000000*t^15-593320281806964761068783956971186835947520000000*t^16-34901193047468515356987291586540402114560000000*t^17-
1938955169303806408721516199252244561920000000*t^18-102050272068621389932711378908012871680000000*t^19-5102513603431069496635568945400643584000000*t^20-
242976838258622356982646140257173504000000*t^21-11044401739028288953756642738962432000000*t^22-480191379957751693641593162563584000000*t^23-20007974164906320568399715106816000000*t^24-
800318966596252822735988604272640000*t^25-30781498715240493182153407856640000*t^26-1140055507971870117857533624320000*t^27-40716268141852504209197629440000*t^28-
1404009246270776007213711360000*t^29-46800308209025866907123712000*t^30-1509687361581479577649152000*t^31-47177730049421236801536000*t^32-1429628183315795054592000*t^33-42047887744582207488000*
t^34-1201368221273777356800*t^35-33371339479827148800*t^36-901928094049382400*t^37-23734949843404800*t^38-608588457523200*t^39-15214711438080*t^40-371090522880*t^41-8835488640*t^42-205476480*t^43-
4669920*t^44-103776*t^45-2256*t^46-48*t^47-t^48)*%e^(-t))/(12413915592536072670862289047373375038521486354677760000000000

Answer (score 0):

For a crude bound:

$$\int_0^{30} \frac{1}{48!} t^{48} (e^{-t}) \, dt = \mathbb{P}(X\le 30)$$

where $X$ is a $\Gamma(49,1)$ random variable, i.e. a sum of $49$ i.i.d. standard exponential random variables. Thus, for $\beta>0$:

$$\mathbb{P}(X\le 30)=\mathbb{P}(e^{-\beta X}\ge e^{-30\beta})\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{-\beta X}]}{e^{-30\beta}}=\frac{e^{30\beta}}{(1+\beta)^{49}}$$

and optimising over $\beta$, we choose $\beta=\beta^{opt}=\dfrac{19}{30}$ to obtain the numerical bound

$$\int_0^{30} \frac{1}{48!} t^{48} (e^{-t}) \, dt \le e^{19}\left(\frac{30}{49}\right)^{49}=0.00647\cdots$$

One could also obtain an approximate bound by appealing to the Central Limit Theorem in a similar way, ultimately looking at $\mathbb{P}\left(Z\le -\dfrac{19}{7}\right)\approx 0.0033\cdots$.

Checking with WolframAlpha, though, both bounds are actually very crude - the actual value is $0.00089\cdots$.